# is there a public API on the iPhone SDK to read Wifi throughput?

Tags: iphone, ios4

is there a public API on the iPhone SDK to read Wifi throughput?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you:

**iPhone signal testing with code**
http://blog.vladalexa.com/2010/07/07/iphone-signal-testing-with-code/